# VB Script to Copy lines from text file containing Keyword

Tags: vbscript, copy, line, keyword

VB Script to Copy lines from text file containing Keyword "Failed". I have a script I am editing that has, so far only been able to copy only instance if the failed lines. In this case, the file only has 2 lines that need to be logged but the are over 12,000 total successful lines. Example below.

```
1111 ,1 ,xxxx ,xxxx ,1 ,10/01/2022 ,07/29/2022 ,1111 ,200 , , , , , ,Failed, , An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details ,

2222 ,2 ,xxxxo ,Kxxxx ,2 ,10/01/2022 ,07/29/2022 ,2222 ,0 , , , , , ,Successfully imported, , ,

33333 ,3 ,Uxxxx ,Jxxxx ,1 ,07/25/2022 ,07/29/2022 ,3333 ,200 , , , , , ,Failed, , An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details ,
```

The current script creates blank lines for the successful lines and only logs the 1 failed line. Trying to get this to all lines containing Failed.

Here is what I am working with.

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim StdIn:  Set StdIn = WScript.StdIn
    Dim StdOut: Set StdOut = WScript
    Main()
    Sub Main()
    Dim objFSO, filepath, objInputFile, tmpStr, ForWriting, ForReading, count, text, objOutputFile, index, LOGFILE, foundFirstMatch
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    LOGFILE = "c:\New folder\Errorlog.csv"
    ForReading = 1
    ForWriting = 2
    Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(LOGFILE, ForReading, False)
    
    text="Fail"
    foundFirstMatch = false
    Do until objInputFile.AtEndOfStream
        tmpStr = objInputFile.ReadLine
        If foundStrMatch(tmpStr)=true Then
            If foundFirstMatch = false Then
                index = getIndex(tmpStr)
                foundFirstMatch = true
                text = text & vbCrLf & textSubstitution(tmpStr,index,"true")
            End If
            If index = getIndex(tmpStr) Then
                text = text & vbCrLf & textSubstitution(tmpStr,index,"false")
            ElseIf index < getIndex(tmpStr) Then
                index = getIndex(tmpStr)
                text = text & vbCrLf & textSubstitution(tmpStr,index,"true")
            End If
        Else
            text = text & vbCrLf & textSubstitution(tmpStr,index,"false")
        End If
    Loop
    Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\New folder\Log2.txt", ForWriting, true)
    objOutputFile.Write(text)
    End Sub
    Function textSubstitution(tmpStr,index,foundMatch)
    'Dim strToAdd
    'strToAdd = "<tr><td><a href=" & chr(34) & "../../Logs/CF5.0_Features/Beginning_of_CF5.0_Features_TC" & CStr(index) & ".html" & chr(34) & ">Beginning_of_CF5.0_Features_TC" & CStr(index) & "</a></td></tr>"
    'If foundMatch = "false" Then
        'textSubstitution = tmpStr
    If foundMatch = "true" Then
        textSubstitution = tmpStr
    End If
    End Function
    Function getIndex(tmpStr)
    Dim substrToFind, charAtPos, char1, char2
    substrToFind = "Failed"
    charAtPos = len(substrToFind) + 1
    char1 = Mid(tmpStr, charAtPos, 1)
    char2 = Mid(tmpStr, charAtPos+1, 1)
    'If IsNumeric(char2) Then
        'getIndex = CInt(char1 & char2)
    'Else
        'getIndex = CInt(char1)
    'End If
    End Function

Function foundStrMatch(tmpStr)
Dim substrToFind
substrToFind = "Failed"
If InStr(tmpStr, substrToFind) > 0 Then
    foundStrMatch = true
Else
    foundStrMatch = false
End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is your question? What is not working as intended?

Comment: The only thing you're writing is your `text` variable that contains the word "Fail".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write matched lines as you find them, like this:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
LOGFILE = "c:\New folder\Errorlog.csv"
OUTFILE = "C:\New folder\Log2.txt"
ForReading = 1
ForWriting = 2

Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(LOGFILE, ForReading, False)
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(OUTFILE, ForWriting, true)
text="Fail"

Do until objInputFile.AtEndOfStream
  tmpStr = objInputFile.ReadLine
  If InStr(tmpStr,text)>0 Then objOutputFile.WriteLine(tmpStr)
Loop

objInputFile.Close
objOutputFile.Close
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. As you see I'm trying to do a lot more here. I will re organize to get this cleaned up.